# "function is not an element of std" when using cppimport

Tags: c++, c++11, pybind11

I want to use this Github Repo: https://github.com/zekyll/OMPEval to get the equity of ranges. I also want to use this cpp code in my main python code, so I am trying to import my cpp code, which uses this github repo, into my main python code. Because I am still just trying out if the code works, I use python in cmd (on my windows 10 machine), so my code looks like this in the command line:

```
import cppimport.import_hook
import Scoring
```

Where Scoring is the main cpp file.

Scoring.cpp

```
//cppimport

/*
<%
setup_pybind11(cfg)
%>
*/

#include <omp/EquityCalculator.h>

#include "Scoring.h"

#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <iterator>

#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/complex.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>
#include <pybind11/chrono.h>


namespace py = pybind11;
using namespace pybind11::literals;


// here is a bunch of crap from my previous attempts trying to get a different repo working but it is unnecessary as I am not using it anymore


double montecarlo_omp(){
    omp::EquityCalculator eq;
    std::vector<omp::CardRange> ranges{"QQ+,AKs,AcQc", "A2s+", "random"};
    uint64_t board = omp::CardRange::getCardMask("2c4c5h");
    uint64_t dead = omp::CardRange::getCardMask("Jc");
    double stdErrMargin = 2e-5; // stop when standard error below 0.002%
    auto callback = [&eq](const omp::EquityCalculator::Results& results) {
        std::cout << results.equity[0] << " " << 100 * results.progress
                << " " << 1e-6 * results.intervalSpeed << std::endl;
        if (results.time > 5) // Stop after 5s
            eq.stop();
    };
    double updateInterval = 0.25; // Callback called every 0.25s.
    unsigned threads = 0; // max hardware parallelism (default)
    eq.start(ranges, board, dead, false, stdErrMargin, callback, updateInterval, threads);
    eq.wait();
    auto r = eq.getResults();
    std::cout << std::endl << r.equity[0] << " " << r.equity[1] << " " << r.equity[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << r.wins[0] << " " << r.wins[1] << " " << r.wins[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << r.hands << " " << r.time << " " << 1e-6 * r.speed << " " << r.stdev << std::endl;
}


PYBIND11_MODULE(Scoring, m) {
    m.def("montecarlo", &montecarlo_omp);
}
```

Now this code is just straight up from the README of the repo and I haven't changed anything. But when I run my cmd python code it throws this error:

```
.rendered.Scoring.cpp
C:\Dokumente\Programmierung\AI\RL\Poker AI\gym_env\PokerEquityCalculator\EquityCalculatorMontecarlo\omp/EquityCalculator.h(79): error C2039: "function" ist kein Member von "std".
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include\iostream(19): note: Siehe Deklaration von "std"
C:\Dokumente\Programmierung\AI\RL\Poker AI\gym_env\PokerEquityCalculator\EquityCalculatorMontecarlo\omp/EquityCalculator.h(79): error C2061: Syntaxfehler: Bezeichner "function"
C:\Dokumente\Programmierung\AI\RL\Poker AI\gym_env\PokerEquityCalculator\EquityCalculatorMontecarlo\omp/EquityCalculator.h(205): error C2039: "function" ist kein Member von "std".
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include\iostream(19): note: Siehe Deklaration von "std"
C:\Dokumente\Programmierung\AI\RL\Poker AI\gym_env\PokerEquityCalculator\EquityCalculatorMontecarlo\omp/EquityCalculator.h(205): error C2143: Syntaxfehler: Es fehlt ";" vor "<"
C:\Dokumente\Programmierung\AI\RL\Poker AI\gym_env\PokerEquityCalculator\EquityCalculatorMontecarlo\omp/EquityCalculator.h(205): error C4430: Fehlender Typspezifizierer - int wird angenommen. Hinweis: "default-int" wird von C++ nicht unterstützt.
C:\Dokumente\Programmierung\AI\RL\Poker AI\gym_env\PokerEquityCalculator\EquityCalculatorMontecarlo\omp/EquityCalculator.h(205): error C2238: Unerwartete(s) Token vor ";"
C:\Dokumente\Programmierung\AI\RL\Poker AI\gym_env\PokerEquityCalculator\EquityCalculatorMontecarlo\.rendered.Scoring.cpp(71): warning C4244: "Initialisierung": Konvertierung von "__int64" in "int", möglicher Datenverlust
C:\Dokumente\Programmierung\AI\RL\Poker AI\gym_env\PokerEquityCalculator\EquityCalculatorMontecarlo\.rendered.Scoring.cpp(158): warning C4244: "Initialisierung": Konvertierung von "__int64" in "int", möglicher Datenverlust
C:\Dokumente\Programmierung\AI\RL\Poker AI\gym_env\PokerEquityCalculator\EquityCalculatorMontecarlo\.rendered.Scoring.cpp(286): warning C4267: "Argument": Konvertierung von "size_t" nach "_Ty", Datenverlust möglich
        with
        [
            _Ty=int
        ]
C:\Dokumente\Programmierung\AI\RL\Poker AI\gym_env\PokerEquityCalculator\EquityCalculatorMontecarlo\.rendered.Scoring.cpp(456): error C2660: "omp::EquityCalculator::start": Funktion akzeptiert keine 8 Argumente
C:\Dokumente\Programmierung\AI\RL\Poker AI\gym_env\PokerEquityCalculator\EquityCalculatorMontecarlo\omp/EquityCalculator.h(77): note: Siehe Deklaration von "omp::EquityCalculator::start"
C:\Dokumente\Programmierung\AI\RL\Poker AI\gym_env\PokerEquityCalculator\EquityCalculatorMontecarlo\.rendered.Scoring.cpp(456): note: bei Anpassung der Argumentliste "(std::vector<omp::CardRange,std::allocator<omp::CardRange>>, uint64_t, uint64_t, bool, double, montecarlo_omp::<lambda_8f75a3f669e61d2a43f417576367e451>, double, unsigned int)"
error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

(I am german so sorry for the german error)

In VS Code, which is the program I am writing the code in, it shows no problems and no red squiggles. I think it has something to do with the setup of cppimport.

I am using the latest cppimport, which I have intalled through pip.
In my error message though, it also says right at the beginnig:

```
cl : Befehlszeile warning D9002 : Unbekannte Option "-std=c++11" wird ignoriert.
cl : Befehlszeile warning D9002 : Unbekannte Option "-fvisibility=hidden" wird ignoriert.
```

I would appreciate any further help! Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Maybe you try to compile with the flags `/std:c++14 /EHsc` (just a suggestion, could not fix the issue)

Comment: It looks like the library has a bug. It uses `std::function` https://github.com/zekyll/OMPEval/blob/4aec210ff75b0851af0ee170b35a7899e1a4fe8f/omp/EquityCalculator.h#L76 but doesn't include `functional`. This could work with some compilers and cause error with others. As a workaround you could try to add `#include <functional>` before `#include <omp/EquityCalculator.h>` in your code.

Comment: @jabaa I did that and it wanted to create the .lib files but then the following error occured: .rendered.Scoring.obj : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: __cdecl omp::HandEvaluator::HandEvaluator(void)" (??0HandEvaluator@omp@@QEAA@XZ)".
.rendered.Scoring.obj : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: __cdecl omp::CombinedRange::CombinedRange(void)" (??0CombinedRange@omp@@QEAA@XZ)".

Comment: @jabaa here is the continuation: .rendered.Scoring.obj : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: bool __cdecl omp::EquityCalculator::start(class std::vector<class omp::CardRange,class std::allocator<class omp::CardRange> > const &,unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64,bool,double,class std::function<void __cdecl(struct omp::EquityCalculator::Results const &)>,double,unsigned int)" (?start@EquityCalculator@omp@@QEAA_NAEBV?$vector@VCardRange@omp@@V?$allocator@VCardRange@omp@@@std@@@std@@_K1_NNV?$function@$$A6AXAEBUResults@EquityCalculator@omp@@@Z@4@NI@Z)".

Comment: @jabaa still the error: .rendered.Scoring.obj : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: static unsigned __int64 __cdecl omp::CardRange::getCardMask(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?getCardMask@CardRange@omp@@SA_KAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)".
.rendered.Scoring.obj : error LNK2001: Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: __cdecl omp::CardRange::CardRange(char const *)" (??0CardRange@omp@@QEAA@PEBD@Z)".

Comment: @PatricioLoncomilla where should I add the flags to? But thanks for the advice!

Comment: The "-std=c++11" flag is for g++. Then I think cppimport is not designed to be used easily with Visual Studio: https://pypi.org/project/cppimport/ (see the last lines in the documentation page)

Comment: @PatricioLoncomilla Sorry for this nooby question, but how would I use cppimport with g++, because I have g++ on my machine?

Comment: I am sorry, but I have not used cppimport actually (and I usually program on linux). Sorry for not being able to be more helpful.

Comment: @PatricioLoncomilla I am not sure if that might help, but I have Mingw64 on my machine. Do you maybe know how to do that? Because I just tried it out with Mingw, but it gave me a totally different error than I get in cmd. First line of the error: C:/Dokumente/Programmierung/AI/RL/Poker AI/gym_env/PokerEquityCalculator/EquityCalculatorMontecarlo/.rendered.Scoring.cpp:465: undefined reference to `omp::CardRange::CardRange(char const*)'